# How can I prevent webpack from analyzing a dynamic import?

Tags: webpack, electron, frontend, dynamic-import

I have a front end app that can either run in a browser or electron.

When it runs in the context of electron, it has access to the `node` environment.

On the front end app, I'd like to import the electron node module, which is obviously unavailable in the browser.

So I have this dynamic import, which in theory I'd like it to fail when the app runs in the browser and succeed when it runs in the electron/node context.

```
const electron = await import('electron');

console.log(electron);
```

However, webpack complains at build time with all sorts of errors, such as

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '.../app/node_modules/electron'

The reason I'm using a dynamic import was to avoid build errors in the first place, since I thought the code would only be executed at runtime, but webpack needs to analyze all imports to create the bundle.

How can I tell webpack to ignore this specific dynamic import or all dynamic imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing electron on the front end, I used the [`preload`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) option to load the node stuff.

Comment: It's awesome that you solved your original problem, but that question that **you** stated was about *webpack ignoring dynamic import*, which still not solved by your proposed "solution". I have 20Mb of .js files which I cannot afford to append to final build nor move them to any server.